# Passing/routing objects that contain function prototypes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I've been doing some work with NodeJS, ExpressJS and AngularJS.

I'm currently working on a graph-plotting project where it is required that all the processing be done on the backend, so the front end only displays results. This requires me routing some objects that contain both data **and** function prototypes to the frontend. So far, I haven't had any luck on this last part. When I call `$http.get` from the front end, and my route responds with `res.send(object)`, in the `console.log` on the node backend, the object is printed complete with its prototype functions, but in my browser on the front end, the retrieved object only prints the data/text part, and discards all the functions completely.

Please see code snippets below to get the gist:

`sample backend ExpressJS routes code snippet`

```
// let's create an object, 
function Person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    // a function prototype
    this.fooBar = function(){
      return 'Yes';
    }
};
// open up a route
app.get('/getObject', function(req, res){
  var baby = new Person("John", "Doe");
  console.log(baby)
  //this console logs the following, as expected:
  // Person { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', fooBar: [Function] }

  // respond with the entire object
  res.send(baby)
});
```

`sample front end AngularJS code snippet`

```
$http.get('/getObject')
.success(function(data){
   console.log(data)
   // THIS, however, only console logs the data, and discards the function
   // Object {firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"}
})
.error(function(err){
   console.log(err)
});
```

It's got me scratching my head, trying to figure out if the issue is from Express/Node, or from Angular's end, or maybe both? I'd appreciate some help on this, as I'd really love to pass the entire object (including the prototype functions) to the front end to be used for some minimal manipulation. If this isn't possible, at least point me in the direction of a suitable workaround :-). Thanks!

Comment: sending executable scripts over the wire is normally a bad idea. I suggest you reconsider your design. Your frontend should only receive data, preferably in JSON format.

Comment: I knew something was up with the design, but just wanted to know if it was possible. Seems this approach might be wonky after all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Functions are not serializable.** For this reason, they will be skipped and not sent with the HTTP call.

From [MDN's docs for `JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

> If `undefined`, a function, or a symbol is encountered during conversion it is either omitted (when it is found in an object) or censored to null (when it is found in an array). `JSON.stringify` can also just return undefined when passing in "pure" values like `JSON.stringify(function(){})` or `JSON.stringify(undefined)`.

Instead, only transfer the data and rehydrate your JS object in the client.

Comment: Was looking for some kind of documentation on this but couldn't find any. Thanks for this @TimoSta!
You wouldn't happen to know any modules or methods where I can do the data crunching in the node backend and just pass the graph results to the front via HTTP call?